# Discovered 2 eggs cracked in late stage of brining

Tags: food-safety, eggs, food-preservation, brining

One more week to go brining my salted chicken eggs. I just saw 2 eggs with cracks that were not there earlier. Do I need to take them out or will it be ok? I have 5 days left.

Comment: Can you share the general brining procedure you're using?  Or a recipe, if it's linkable.

Comment: As FuzzyChef suggested, it would help to know what your brine solution is (%salinity) and any other details about how you're doing the brining process. What temp are you keeping the eggs at? Is there anything aside from salt in your brine solution? How long have they been brining before you noticed the cracks and how often do you check?